# Jquery animate not detecting scroll properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to make a feature where a button slides up to take you back to the top after scrolling. However for some reason it just won't work. It works fine when I use

```
        if (scroll >= 84) {
            $("#ID").fadeIn();
        } else {
            $("#ID").fadeOut();
        }
```

But when it just doesnt work with either animate or css.
The way i keep track of the scroll is with a eventlistener, and declaring a let with the value:

```
let scroll = this.scrollY;
```

I hope this is enough information to give you an idea of what im going for. Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Did you declare and reset the variable *inside* the event listener? It doesn't 'update' automatically.

Comment: Im still very new to javascript and jquery so im not sure what you mean by reset? And the rest of the code is in the eventlistener

Comment: In my answer, I reset `scrollDistance` to `window.scrollY` every time the event listener for scrolling fired. This is the equivalent of 'resetting'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (run and scroll down):

```js
var timeout;

for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  document.body.innerHTML += "Example Text<br>"
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  var scrollDistance = window.scrollY
  if (scrollDistance >= 100) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    document.querySelector("button").style.display = "";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.querySelector("button").style.opacity = "1"
    }, 1);
    document.querySelector("button").style.cursor = "pointer";
  } else {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    document.querySelector("button").style.opacity = "0";
    document.querySelector("button").style.cursor = "";
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      document.querySelector("button").style.display = "none"
    }, 500);
  }
})

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  window.scroll({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
})
```

```css
button {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ffcccb;
  border: 2px solid black;
  opacity: 0;
  outline: none;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

button>div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  transform: translate(0, 4px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<button>
<div></div>
</button>
```

Note that most of the code is just setup. This is the actual code that does the scrolling work:

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  window.scroll({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
})
```

It simply listens for the click of the button, and scrolls to the top.

Comment: sorry it took so long to answer, but this works perfectly, so thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem! Would you consider marking my answer as correct?